# Perl: получение рандомного числа от единицы до двух

Tags: perl, случайные-числа

Здраствуйте, с синтаксисом перла не знаком, но нужно реализовать рандомное значение между единицей и двойкой после выполнения функции. Есть функция, которая зависит от параметра, который задается 2.

```
Generate(17, "test",3,1 , 2);
```

вообщем, неважно, что значат первые аргументы, важен лишь последний. В самой функции его значение задается так:

```
my %values = ('CAT' => $dbCategoryUrl,'CATNAME' =>$dbCategoryName , 'TEST' =>$test );
```

и значение принимает только 2 после выполнения. подскажите, как реализовать функцию так, чтобы выдавалось рандомное значение 1 или 2 после выполнения. Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Что бы получить случайное число 1 или 2, пользуйтесь такой конструкцией

```
 int(rand(2)+1)
```

> А можно ли сделать, чтобы они чредовались?

можно и так

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.018;
use strict;
use warnings;

{
my $counter = 1;
sub getNext {

    $counter = 3 - $counter;
    return $counter;
}
}
for (1..100) {
    print getNext(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Тоесть, моя функция будет выглядеть так: my %values = ('CAT' => $dbCategoryUrl,'CATNAME' =>$dbCategoryName , 'TEST' =>int(rand(2)+1) );, или в аргументах первой изменить на Generate(17, "test",3,1 ,int(rand(2)+1));

Comment: Я бы оставлял генерирование внутри функции ( то есть, первый вариант). Судя по ее имени, это ожидаемо. А передавать с внешнего мира параметр внурь черного ящика... не, слишком запутано.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли сделать, чтобы они чредовались?